# Refreshing new messages value every second

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

In my Django site i have a span ,which shows how many new messages does the user have *like in this image below :* 
[image]

 Now I am refreshing this value in every django view possible and it's the part of my base.html

### Views.py

```
def someView(request,pk):
...
    mcount = UserMessage.objects.filter(receiver = request.user.pk, isRed = 0).count()
...
    return render(request, 'app/somehtml.html', {...'mcount':mcount...})
```

### base.html

```
...
  <span class="messageCount"aria-hidden="true"> {{ mcount }} </span>
...
```

What i want to do is to refresh it every few seconds without user reloading the page.
How could i achieve that ?

Comment: You could poll the server and refresh that span using say Ajax

Comment: You can do something as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function autoReloadSpan(){
    $.ajax({ url: "/poll/",
                     data: {},
                     type: 'GET',
                     success: function(data) {
                         $('.messageCount').html(data);
                     },
    });
}

autoReloadSpan(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
    autoReloadSpan() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do the auto-refresh on the client side using Javascript.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    location.href = "http://yourwebsite.com";
}, 30000);
```

This refreshes the page every 30 seconds.

There's also the meta html tag:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
```

This also refreshes the page every 30 seconds.

Comment: Well since i have forms in some of my pages ,I don't want to refresh the whole page, only that value

Comment: You can use ajax to only refresh the span and not the entire page.  Take a look at $.ajax().  You can have it call someView directly and process the response to update the span based on the results.